# Is there a way to automate texting based on a group a contact is added to in Google Contacts

Tags: google-contacts, automation, sms

I'm wondering if there's a way to send a generic pre-written message to any/every contact that's added to a Google contact group.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an Android phone, you should be able to get something done with [If This Then That](https://ifttt.com).

Start with the [Google Contacts](https://ifttt.com/google_contacts) channel and the [New contact added to group](https://ifttt.com/channels/google_contacts/triggers/119302308-new-contact-added-to-group) trigger.

For your action, you'll want the [Android SMS Channel](https://ifttt.com/android_messages) and the [send an SMS](https://ifttt.com/channels/android_messages/actions/140837842-send-an-sms) trigger.

Simply use the `{{PhoneNumber}}` ingredient from your trigger as the Phone number in the action, along with whatever your message is. You should be able to customize the message with other ingredients from the trigger.

One downside is that there's only one `{{PhoneNumber}}` field available and, as I'm sure you know, a person could have multiple phone numbers. There's no way to designate one as a mobile number and only use that.

---

Unfortunately, while there is a generic [SMS channel](https://ifttt.com/sms), it's only for sending messages to yourself. Can you imagine the havoc someone could cause by automating the sending of SMS messages, especially when there are still people in the world who have to pay for incoming messages? By using the Android phone (and the IF app on it) you'll be using your own device and data and, if necessary, IFTTT can cut you off.